# Setting up a backup ssytem with replication on a JBOD

Tags: linux, backup

I have approximately 5, and soon to be 6 laptop hard drives that aren't being used at the moment. They are not the same size, so I'm not sure that LVM is the best case for this. I am looking to have the drives store backups, with redunancy, produced by my central linux server. [It's a small personal server with very few requests]. The type of backups that I'm looking to do is backuping up archieves [tar.gz files created via a cron script].

At the moment, all of the drives have a USB enclosure that sits on a USB hub.

Is there a tool that can make this easier to do, rather than creating everything via shell script?

Comment: There's no 'best' way to do things but there's solutions that work better in some situations

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that the term JBOD existed. I'm only familar with RAID and LVM configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few pieces to the puzzle. You have a JBOD, and want to treat it as a single unit - [greyhole](http://www.greyhole.net/) would work great for this. It exposes the drives as a single samba share, and lets you have redundant copies. I'd probably pair this up with [rdiffbackup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) for efficient incremental storage.

Another way I can think of to do this would be to use inotify/[incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to trigger a backup process to run. Have one master drive, and a series of scripts that backup to each other backup drive. Needs more setup (and testing!), but would probably work as well.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from opening up a Samba share? I'm not really thrilled about using Samba. [All my OSes are linux]

Comment: Unfortunately it entirely relies on that to work I think. I guess you could mount the share internally and expose it some other way.

Comment: Does this account for redundancy? If one disk fails, I'd rather not lose data.

Comment: yup. Does redundancy. I have an idea for an alternate method but its not as elegant.

Comment: I'm going to go with the Greyhole route.. It sounds like a more mature option

Answer (score 2):

I think [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) is what you're looking for. It works on local files but also over ssh/rsync and ftp.